# Embedding an Instagram-Post in dark mode

Tags: instagram, embed, darkmode

Instagram has a **dark mode**, which is - at the time - only accessible over the URL parameter '?theme="dark"' if you are using it in the browser-version/on pc.

As my page has a dark mode as well, i'd obviously like to embed posts in the dark mode style when my page-style is set to dark as well, because it looks very bad otherwise.

My first thought, to just change the URLs in the embed-code to have the 'theme="dark"' attribute, before using it, doesn't work and as there's no real documentation about this, i'd like to know if someone figured out the correct **parameter** **and** **where to put it in the embed-code**.

btw: I'm not planning on using the API for embedding posts

Comment: @ZecKa no, i sadly didn't